# how to add datetime value from excel cell using VBA into SQL table

Tags: sql, vba, excel

Can anyone help?

```
strSql = "INSERT INTO EmailRT (rs.Fields(0).Value, rs.Fields(1).Value) " & _
        " VALUES (" & _
        "'" & shtSheetToWork.Cells(2, 1).Value & "', " & _
        "'" & shtSheetToWork.Cells(2, 2).Value & "')"
```

In cell (2,2), the value is 21/10/2014 22:32 how do i add this to Sql table into column rs.Fields(1).Value whose data type is datetime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You can format the cell as you need (in <kbd>Ctrl+1</kbd>). And then use `shtSheetToWork.Cells(2, 1).Text`

2) You can use VBA Format. `Format(shtSheetToWork.Cells(2, 1).Text, "yyyyMMdd")`